# How do I use an unregistered dll from c#?

Tags: c#, dll, interop, interopservices

I have a custom dll (not registered) that I need to access via c#.  How do I do this without registering the DLL?

Edit: It is a C++ dll.

Comment: What kind of dll is it? An .NET-assembly, a native DLL, a COM-Object? What do you mean by register a dll?

Comment: Assuming you mean "not referenced by the current assembly" when you write "not registered", use [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Registration-Free COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1h056h.aspx):

> Registration-free COM interop
>   activates a component without using
>   the Windows registry to store assembly
>   information. Instead of registering a
>   component on a computer during
>   deployment, you create Win32-style
>   manifest files at design time that
>   contain information about binding and
>   activation. These manifest files,
>   rather than registry keys, direct the
>   activation of an object.
>
> Using registration-free activation for
>   your assemblies instead of registering
>   them during deployment offers two
>   advantages:
>
> - You can control which DLL version is activated when more than
>     one version is installed on a
>     computer.
> - End users can use XCOPY or FTP to copy your application to an
>     appropriate directory on their
>     computer. The application can then be
>     run from that directory.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to use the functions exported from this dll via P/Invoke? If so, you only need to copy the dll to the same folder as your exe file. Then write C# declarations for the functions in the C++ dll that you want to use. See [DllImportAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx).